# Error Parsing TMX file with Swift 2.1.1

Tags: swift, parsing, swift2, tmx

Before converting my Xcode project to Swift 2 I had the following function that I was using to parse my TMX level files. It provided a variable attributeDict to use within the function.

```
func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, didStartElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?, attributes attributeDict: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {

// my function code

}
```

After converting to Swift 2 (I am now on 2.1.1), I was prompted to change it to an @objc func and change some of the syntax. Now where the variable attributeDict was accessible within the function, now the variable is not created, leaving numerous errors

```
@objc func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, didStartElement elementName: String?, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?, attributes: attributeDict<NSObject,AnyObject>) {

// my function code

}
```

I must have changed the syntax incorrectly but can't work out, from the documentation, what I've done wrong. Hoping it's obvious to someone else. Any assistance would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The conversion has munged the declaration of `attributeDict`. Change that one bit back to how it was before:

```
attributes attributeDict: [NSObject : AnyObject]
```

Note that you might find you get an error if you are not allowed to use `NSObject` as a key for a dictionary (dictionary keys must conform to `Hashable`) and you should probably reconsider the type of your dictionary keys.